# How do I set the manual focus magnification on the Sony NEX-5R?

Tags: manual-focus, sony-nex, magnification, focus-assist

The NEX-5R has a manual assist function: if you enable it, and put the camera in manual focus mode, then when you rotate the focus ring, the camera shows a magnified view so that you can focus better.

[According](http://kenrockwell.com/sony/nex-5r.htm) [to](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/announcements/sony-introduces-nex-5r) [multiple](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/sony-nex-5r/sony-nex-5rA.HTM) [sources](http://photographylife.com/reviews/sony-nex-5r/5), you can choose between a magnification of 4.8x and 9.6x, but I don't find that option in the camera settings, and neither is it mentioned in the manual.

Is it hidden somewhere where it's hard to find, or are these sources all wrong when they claim this camera has this capability?

Comment: I would try the same method you use to zoom into photos during playback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a NEX-3N. There, when the magnified view is displayed, you can switch between the two magnifications via the button next to the lower right corner of the display (next to it, the magnification you can switch *to* is displayed, while in the upper left corner you see the current magnification).

To complete the answer for others, here's how to enable the feature:

- In the Camera menu, set AF/MF Select to Manual Focus
- In the Setup menu, set MF Assist to On